# Copying values from ag-grid cell (text selection) not working in chrome. - Angular

Tags: css, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I tried following approach to solve this issue , it works with FF but not with Chrome.

```
  ::ng-deep div.ag-cell-value {
    -webkit-touch-callout: default;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    -khtml-user-select: text;
    -moz-user-select: text;
    -ms-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
    cursor:auto;
  }
```

Text selecting randomly even from other cells in chrome check below,

[image: i selected only one cell here]

Please check the issue by adding this css to below standard template ,
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world

Comment: please creare stackblitz example of your code

Comment: Hi i was unable to install aggrid in stackblitz so Please add above css in this standard template https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using CSS, have you tried using the `enableCellTextSelection` option?

```
<ag-grid-angular 
    style="width: 500px; height: 200px;" 
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    enableCellTextSelection="true"
    [rowData]="rowData" 
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Comment: it doesn't work , do i need to add any api to use this feature? @guilherme

Comment: I just forked the stackblitz example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-kub4rq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: it's working in stackblitz but not in my project i don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211780/discussion-between-umesh-c-and-guilherme-lopes).

Comment: This is version specific i was using version "ag-grid":"^19.1.2", if we are using latest version ( >23) of ag-grid then only enableCellTextSelection="true" will support .

Comment: Yeah.. My bad.. having a `@since` tag in the gridProperties would help

Comment: can you please tell me more about @since usage? as i am getting following error if i include in my gridProperties.  [Error: Found the synthetic property @since]

Comment: `@since` is not related to ag-Grid, it's just a documentation thing that helps users track when a feature was added. See: https://jsdoc.app/tags-since.html

Comment: unfortunately enableCellTextSelection="true" does not work for pinned columns :( would you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You may try below if you are using community edition,

```
::ng-deep .ag-unselectable {
   -moz-user-select: text;
   -webkit-user-select: text;
    -ms-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
}
```

for Enterprise edition you may check - [Clipboard Feature](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/clipboard/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a regular text selection as if the grid were a regular table, set enableCellTextSelection=true and ensureDomOrder=true in the gridOptions.

https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/selection-overview/